# C++ boost, wait for var init from different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, boost

My TCP client class has methods that sends requests to the server.
In some cases i need to wait for a response in order to make another request.
Of course i can write something like this:

```
class MyClass {
private:
    SomeResponsMsgType* some_resp_msg_type;
    TCP_client tcp_client;

    void handle_resp(T resp) {
        //handles responses
        //initializes some_resp_msg_type and others
    }

public:
    MyClass() : some_resp_msg_type(nullptr) {}

    void init() {
        tcp_client.run(this, MyClass::handle_resp);
    }

    SomeResponsMsgType* make_request(int v) {
        Request req(v);

        some_resp_msg_type = nullptr;

        send_message(req);

        int timeout = 10;
        while(!some_resp_msg_type && !timeout) {
            Sleep(100);
            --timeout;
        }
        SomeResponsMsgType* ret = some_resp_msg_type;
        some_resp_msg_type = nullptr;

        return ret;
    }
};

//and use it like this:

void foo() {
    MyClass my_class;
    my_class.init();
    SomeResponsMsgType* resp = my_class.make_request(1);
    if(!resp)
        ...

    AnotherResponsMsgType* resp2 = my_class.make_another_request(resp->some_var);
}
```

But this code looks ugly and unsafe.
Please help me with an example. Thanks.

Comment: I would search for some examples using std::future and std::promise

Comment: In order to return a response, you need to get it from the server first. This operation normally waits.

Comment: @n.m. depends on "normally". Quite probably, `TCP_client` is designed to run async here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, I'd look at futures here, and prefer to let the caller decide when to await the value:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace ba = boost::asio;

using ba::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct Request {
    Request(int v) : _v(v) {}
    int _v;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Request const& req) {
        return os << req._v;
    }
};

struct SomeResponseMsgType {
    std::string text;
};

class MyClass {
    std::future<SomeResponseMsgType> send_message(Request const& req) {
        std::promise<SomeResponseMsgType> p;

        try {
            // This would be your async call. Here I simplify by 
            tcp::iostream sock(tcp::endpoint{ {}, 6767 });
            sock.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::eofbit | std::ios::badbit);

            sock.expires_after(1500ms);
            sock << req << "\n";

            {
                std::ostringstream oss;
                oss << sock.rdbuf();
                p.set_value(SomeResponseMsgType {oss.str()});
            }
        } catch (...) {
            p.set_exception(std::current_exception());
        }

        return p.get_future();
    }

public:
    std::future<SomeResponseMsgType> make_request(int v) {
        return send_message(Request{v});
    }
};

//and use it like this:

int main() {
    MyClass my_class;
    auto f1 = my_class.make_request(1);
    auto f2 = my_class.make_request(2);

    try {
        {
            SomeResponseMsgType resp = f2.get();
            std::cout << "Second request gave: " << resp.text << "\n";
        }
        {
            SomeResponseMsgType resp = f1.get();
            std::cout << "First request gave: " << resp.text << "\n";
        }
    } catch(boost::system::system_error const& e) {
        std::cerr << "Whoops " << e.code().message() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Of course in your example `send_message` would probably use `TCP_Client` in some async way, but the principle remains the same. To automate more, see [`packaged_task<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task)

Note that the order of the requests is guaranteed here (because `send_message` happens to actually be synchronous). With async code the queuing of the async operations scheduled by `send_message` would dictate whether the requests are sent in order. (And then, the second future might actually be ready before the first if the server happened to respond quicker.)

A silly test with the above:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:6767,reuseaddr,fork "SYSTEM:sleep 1 && /bin/date"&
./sotest 
Second request gave: ma 30 jul 2018  1:14:42 CEST

First request gave: ma 30 jul 2018  1:14:41 CEST
```

Comment: Yes, TCP_Client is async in my case, but that's what i was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more question about Response initialization. In case TCP_Client is async, should i create an array of responses with boost::condition_variable inside and "oss.str()" will look like { while (!response_received) condition.wait(lock);} So i will be able to initialize these responses from handle_packet function?

Comment: If you want to handle them in asynchronous fashion, I'd suggest harnessing it with a Boost Asio `io_service` (or `io_context` in latest boost), so you can avoid the `while` which is pretty error prone and codes for bad performance (if not deadlock)

Comment: In fact you can mix and match by using Asio's `use_future` support. But I guess this will be a tad complex for now, so I'd try to keep it as simple as possible.